# Gnome 1804 - Add .desktop to launcher via commandline

Tags: gnome, launcher, ubuntu-18.04, gnome-3

I'm trying to script adding x.desktop items to the gnome launcher in 18.04.
In unity (16.04) you can use:

`gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites XYZ`

but I can't work out the equivalent (if it even exists) in gnome.
I've found gsettings of:

`org.gnome.gnome-panel.launcher:/`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right, I worked it out so I figured I'd share this back.

For gnome (eg ubuntu 18.04), the following script will add an existing desktop file to favourites:

```
application="'${1}.desktop'"
favourites="/org/gnome/shell/favorite-apps"
dconf write ${favourites} \
  "$(dconf read ${favourites} \
  | sed "s/, ${application}//g" \
  | sed "s/${application}//g" \
  | sed -e "s/]$/, ${application}]/")"
```

For Unity (eg ubuntu 16.04), the following script will add an existing  desktop file to favourites:

```
application="'${1}.desktop'"
favourites="/com/canonical/unity/launcher/favorites"
dconf write ${favourites} \
  "$(dconf read ${favourites} \
  | sed "s/, ${application}//g" \
  | sed "s/${application}//g" \
  | sed -e "s/]$/, ${application}]/")"
```

Scripts usage as follows:

```
./add_favourite.sh google-chrome
```